# Not able to change ion select popover mode

Tags: ionic3

I'm trying to change the mode of ionic ion-select popover. I tried using mode in ion select but it didn't change the mode.

```
<ion-select class="selecttitle popoverselectdropdown" [mode]="md"
interface="popover" [placeholder]="labels.yourLocation">
```

Comment: There are a few existing question with similar requirements. What has your research showed?

Comment: it still showing me popover ios.

Comment: I'd raise this with Ionic on their github.

Comment: anyone faced this before?. even you gave mode in ion select it didn't changing the mode

Comment: Have you reproduced your problem using browser developer mode making sure to force the browser not to cache anything?

Comment: Yes i did. still no change